# passing more than one variable to another page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass more than one variable to other web pages.

I try this code

`string adi = TaskGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;`

`string soyadi = TaskGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;`

`Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?adi=" + adi);`

`Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?soyadi=" + adi);`

but it doesnt work how can I do?

Comment: this is the reason for down votes of your previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest way is to use [`String.Format()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) with [`Server.UrlEncode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("Default2.aspx?adi={0}&soyadi={1}", Server.UrlEncode(adi), Server.UrlEncode(soyadi)));
```

This will ensure that the querystring values will not be broken if there is an ampersand (`&`) for example, in the value.

Then on `Default2.aspx` you can access the values like:

```
Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["adi"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate them like this:

```
Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?adi=" + adi + "&soyadi=" + soyadi);
```

When passing query string parameters, use the `?` symbol just after the name of the page and if you want to add more than one parameter, use the `&` symbol to separate them

In the consuming page:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var adi = this.Request.QueryString["adi"];
        var soyadi = this.Request.QueryString["soyadi"];
    }
```

Comment: please see @curt's reply below. it is more secure and a more recommended way of achieving the same thing. the security implications of this are important!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the session to pass values from one page to another

Set the values in the page  where you want to pass the values from in to a session

```
Session["adi"] = TaskGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

Session["soyadi"] = TaskGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
```

In the Page where you want to retrieve- You do like this..

```
string adi=(string)(Session["adi"]);
string soyadi=(string)(Session["soyadi"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well pass values through `ViewState` or `Session` the diffrent with what you doing now is: People will not see anything in your url and have no idea what happend in backend. It's good when you passing some "topsecret" data ;P